# "Variable is undefined" error in function

Tags: javascript

I am getting a "Variable is undefined" error in a function. The variable "recID" is defined as:

```
var recID = 0;
```

I also have an input:

```
<input type="text" id="rdy">
```

I assign a value to the variable (this is a modified version of how the value is actually being assigned, for this question):

```
recID = 3;
```

Then I call a function:

```
<a href=""><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Next Hypothetical" onclick='reselectState()'></a>
```

The function is:

```
<script>
    function reselectState() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("rdy");
        elem.value = recID;

        var rdy = $("#rdy").val();
        alert(rdy);
        location.href = '/hypothetical.cshtml?recordkey=' + rdy;
    }
    </script>
```

The error I am getting says "recID" is undefined.

Comment: Maybe `recID` is out of scope. To check if that's whats happening, try `window.recID` instead of `var`

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to recID? You may need to double-check that [the variable is in scope](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) (link updated to a more helpful resource).

Comment: make your `recID` as a global variable if you want it to be accessible to other functions

Comment: Can you show your code snippet in a single code block. It's easier to find the exact reason that way :-)

Answer (score 0):

This means `recID` is not a global variable. It would really help if you post more code or a complete file. The other issue could be that  `recID` is never defined.

You should define recID before `reselectState` is called like so:

```
var recID = 0;

function reselectState() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("rdy");
    elem.value = recID;

    ...
}
```

If you are defining it using any of these methods `recID` will not be global:

```
(function(){
  recID = 0;
});

anotherFunction = function(){
  recID = 0;
}
```

If this is the problem you can fix it by using `window`:

```
(function(){
  window.recID = 0;
});

anotherFunction = function(){
  window.recID = 0;
}
```

Comment: Since I am using Microsoft Razor, the variable needed to be passed as "@recID". The code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use window or pass it to the function as a parameter.